# The expected value of a function

Tags: probability, expectation

What is the expected value of $.1\delta(x)+0.9u(x)e^{-x}$?

So I need to integrate
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(.1\delta(x)+0.9u(x)e^{-x})xdx=\int_{0}^{\infty}(.1x\delta(x)+0.9xe^{-x})dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}.1x\delta(x)dx+\int_{0}^{\infty}0.9xe^{-x}dx=0.9$

Does it make sense? The average value is 0.9.... Strange...

Comment: Uhm...what is $.1\delta$? and $u(x)$?

Comment: $\delta$ is delta function and $u(x)$ is a step function

Comment: I assume you mean $u(x)=1_{[0,\infty]}(x)$....the wording is slightly off, you compute the expected value of a random variable which the density function (have you already verified that it is indeed a density function) etc...

Comment: For one, be careful how you break up the integration. You should first fully distribute and separate the integrals before restricting the domain as there is no step function for the Delta function part and so still has the entire range from negative infinity to infinity.

Comment: "The average value of being 0.9.... Strange..." Why "strange"?

Comment: Mean value of being 0.9 does not seems to be right from the function plot

Comment: @Don it's actually a good thing to visualize before computing imho but how did you plot your function?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's fine.  That is the integration for the expectation of this mixed distribution.